# FireBase 'firebase.js:74 Uncaught undefined'

Tags: javascript, firebase

I sometimes get in chrome console: firebase.js:74 Uncaught undefined

If I click on the line the section highlighted in the debugger is:

```
{throw a;},0)},Zc,$c=function(){var a=l.MessageChannel;"undefined"===typeof a&&"undefined"!==typeof window&&window.postMessage&&window.addEventListener&&!x("Presto")&&(a=function(){var a=document.createElement("IFRAME");a.style.display="none";a.src="";document.documentElement.appendChild(a);var b=a.contentWindow,a=b.document;a.open();a.write("");a.close();var c="callImmediate"+Math.random(),d="file:"==b.location.protocol?"*":b.location.protocol+"//"+b.location.host,
```

Any help ?

Comment: Without seeing the minimal code that reproduces this problem, it's impossible to help.

Comment: why ? I can imagine if you have the unminified firebase code it should be pretty easy to see where such an exception can happen at that position and catch it ... anyway it's hard for me to create a sample as it's happening intermittently